# In pgAdmin for postgreSQL, I am unable to query for MAXimum rows from another query that SUMs up and sorts rows. Working with 1 table

Tags: sql, nested, pgadmin

This is the initial query that groups, sums up, and orders the busiest day of the week per month and year for a small retail store:

`SELECT year, month, day_of_week, SUM(total_revenue)`
`FROM vip_sales`
`GROUP BY year, month, day_of_week`
`ORDER BY year, month, SUM DESC`

and returns the table in attached image. And that is what I want to see INITIALLY.

[image]

Now I want to do a query on this result (image) that only shows the MAX sums of each month - essentially ONLY the rows that I circled, which is the best day (highest SUM) is each of the months of January (1) , February(2), ...

I tried the following:

`SELECT year, month, day_of_week, MAX(SUM(total_revenue))`
`FROM vip_sales`
`GROUP BY year, month, day_of_week`
`ORDER BY year, month`

But I got this error:
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
LINE 1: SELECT year, month, day_of_week, MAX(SUM(total_revenue))
^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 38

Then I tried:

`SELECT year, month, day_of_week, MAX(SUM)` 
`FROM` 
 `(SELECT year, month, day_of_week, SUM(total_revenue)`
 `FROM vip_sales`
 `GROUP BY year, month, day_of_week`
 `ORDER BY year, month, SUM DESC)`
`ORDER BY year, month`

And I got another error with hint:
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 3:  (SELECT year, month, day_of_week, SUM(total_revenue)
^
HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
SQL state: 42601
Character: 51

So then I tried:

`SELECT year, month, day_of_week, MAX(SUM)` 
`FROM` 
`(SELECT year, month, day_of_week, SUM(total_revenue)`
 `FROM vip_sales`
 `GROUP BY year, month, day_of_week`
 `ORDER BY year, month, SUM DESC) AS foo`
`GROUP BY foo.year, foo.month, foo.day_of_week`
`ORDER BY foo.year, foo.month, MAX DESC`

AND

`SELECT foo.year, foo.month, foo.day_of_week, MAX(foo.SUM)` 
`FROM` 
 `(SELECT year, month, day_of_week, SUM(total_revenue)`
 `FROM vip_sales`
 `GROUP BY year, month, day_of_week`
 `ORDER BY year, month, SUM DESC) AS foo`
`GROUP BY foo.year, foo.month, foo.day_of_week`
`ORDER BY foo.year, foo.month, MAX DESC`

But they are redundant and both return the SAME results as in the image - all days of the week in that month, and NOT the day of the week which is the day with maximum sales in that month in that year.

I googled 'nested queries' and 'sub queries" but I tried some techniques but got errors with no hints.  I am not finding anything that logically explains how to do SUM and then query the MAXIMUM of the SUMs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to create a custom partition

```
SELECT year, month, day, thesum
FROM (
  SELECT year, month, day, thesum,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year, month ORDER BY thesum DESC) RN
  FROM (
    SELECT year, month, day_of_week, SUM(total_revenue) as thesum
    FROM vip_sales 
    GROUP BY year, month, day_of_week 
    --ORDER BY year, month, SUM DESC
  ) x
) y
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Hogan.  Your answer worked after I changed the typo 'day' column name in the first two lines to 'day_of_week'.  minor.  Thanks again